# How do I decide which family of variance/link functions to use in a generalized linear model?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, modeling, link-function

I'm about to use the glm() function in R, and I know that I have to specify which family of variance/link functions I want to use (either gaussian, binomial, poisson, Gamma, inverse.gaussian, or quasi-which I take to mean user-defined).

I understand that binomial is to be used for things like logistic regression, but it's unclear to me under what scenarios the others should be used. Does anybody have useful advice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on the nature of your dependent variable:

Gaussian is for continuous DV (this is ordinary least squares)

Binomial, as you note, is for logistic regression .

Poisson is for count data (non-negative integers). See also quasipoisson.

Gamma is for continuous DV that is always positive (although often you can use Gaussian here, if the mean is $>> 0$ and the sd isn't huge - that is, if all the values are quite far from 0).

Inverse Gaussian is, I believe, used for survival data (time to event).

Comment: You mean independent variable, right?
And also, are you saying that a binomial link can be used for both count data and binary traits (say, presence or absence of a viral infection)?

Comment: No, I mean dependent variable. Not sure what you are referring to with you second question.

Comment: Does anyone know of (or would anyone be willing to provide) a concise guide to choosing an appropriate family & link function based on the shape of the data/residuals?