# Are MAE and RMSE possible ways of choosing between ols and types of glm?

Tags: regression, goodness-of-fit, mae

I have a longitudinal data set and have fit a number of different regression models [ols, poisson, binomial....and more]. I want to justify the final model selection and assumed one method might be to use MAE and RMSE to show which 'fits' the data best. Is this approach one that has academic precedent? Is there some reason you should not use such to assess model fit?

Comment: That is the main approach that is used to select "better" models, of course assuming this is on a separate set. and not on the same training set (or similar alternatives).

Answer (score 2):

Many would opine that one should rather choose model form by knowledge of the phenomenon being studied, and the goal of the analysis.  Some posts mostly arguing this way is

- [How to decide which glm family to use?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/190763/how-to-decide-which-glm-family-to-use)
- [Choosing the best family and link function for a GLM](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/539555/choosing-the-best-family-and-link-function-for-a-glm)
- [How do I decide which family of variance/link functions to use in a generalized linear model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38282/how-do-i-decide-which-family-of-variance-link-functions-to-use-in-a-generalized)
- [How to choose the family in Generalized Linear Model in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/216284/how-to-choose-the-family-in-generalized-linear-model-in-r)
- [Goodness of fit and which model to choose linear regression or Poisson](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142338/goodness-of-fit-and-which-model-to-choose-linear-regression-or-poisson/142353#142353)